# Multiple animation keyframes doesn't work

Tags: css

```
@keyframes showAnimation {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 20px;
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  to {
    display: none;
  }
}

@mixin points {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  content: '\2026';
  width: 0px;
}

.findingAvailableRobot {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showAnimation 3s 1s forwards;

  &:after {
    @include points;
    animation: ellipsis steps(4, end) 900ms infinite, hide 0s 4s forwards;
  }
}
```

`findingAvailableRobot` I'm trying to make anymation loading process , but also I want to stop this animation after some time , I've found that animation can take multiple keyframes , but it doesn't work , want to hide `:after` , after 4s seconds . Is it possible ? Or what I do wrong ?

Comment: you cannot animate display

Comment: how can I stop prev animation?leave 3 points at the end

Comment: I've made width: 20px in hide keyframe , and it stoped after 4s , thatks @TemaniAfif